# Forward socks proxy to another

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, socks

How can I set up a socks server in Linux that forwards all traffic to a parent socks server?
I tried squid but it does not support socks

Comment: You could just use iptables with -j REDIRECT - not sure what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

The [dante SOCKS server](http://www.inet.no/dante/) provides this capability, for TCP connections (rather than UDP). Here's an excerpt from Debian's man page, the configuration filename [`/etc/danted.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/dante-server/danted.conf.5#ROUTES) might be named differently on other systems:

> ROUTES
>
> The routes are specified with a route keyword. Inside a pair of curly
>   braces ({}) a set of keywords control the behavior of the route. See
>   [dante.conf(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/dante-client/dante.conf.5#ROUTES) for a description. **This is used to perform so-called
>   "server-chaining", where one socks-server connects to another
>   socks-server further upstream.**
>
> The syntax for these routes is the same as the routes used by the
>   client. Please see [dante.conf(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/dante-client/dante.conf.5#ROUTES) for information about the route
>   syntax.
>
> There are however some special things one need to be aware of
>   regarding serverchaining and routes specified for the server:
>
> At present **serverchaining is only supported for the tcp connect command**.